# Why does the up button cause an exception in the 'Building Your First App' Android training

Tags: android

I had done all of the steps on the last part ([Starting Another Activity](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html)) and it does display the message on the second activity but when I click the up button it throws the exception below, I've included the whole error section from the LogCat window.

I've tried searching online for '**bad parentActivityName**' or '**does not have a parent activity name specified**' but I couldn't find any clear information or anything related to the training.

```
E/Activity(17099): getParentActivityIntent: bad parentActivityName 'com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity' in manifest
E/NavUtils(17099): getParentActivityIntent: bad parentActivityName 'com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity' in manifest
D/AndroidRuntime(17099): Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime(17099): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(17099): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Activity DisplayMessageActivity 
    does not have a parent activity name specified. (Did you forget to add the 
    android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY <meta-data>  element in your manifest?)

E/AndroidRuntime(17099):    at android.support.v4.app.NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(NavUtils.java:177)
E/AndroidRuntime(17099):    at com.example.myfirstname.DisplayMessageActivity.onOptionsItemSelected(DisplayMessageActivity.java:55)
E/AndroidRuntime(17099):    at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2548)
E/AndroidRuntime(17099):    at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarView$3.onClick(ActionBarView.java:167)
E/AndroidRuntime(17099):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
E/AndroidRuntime(17099):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
E/AndroidRuntime(17099):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
E/AndroidRuntime(17099):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
E/AndroidRuntime(17099):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
E/AndroidRuntime(17099):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
E/AndroidRuntime(17099):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(17099):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
E/AndroidRuntime(17099):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
E/AndroidRuntime(17099):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
E/AndroidRuntime(17099):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It turns out that I had made a simple mistake, I had got the namespace wrong.

Used in the training: com.example.myfirstapp
What I used: com.example.myfirstname

For some reason I had used a different name than the training so when I copied and pasted from the last part it included the original name.  I hindsight I should have read the error message a bit more carefully and I should have realised my mistake.

The part '**Did you forget to add the android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY**' throw me off a bit since that section was included it was just using the wrong namespace.

Comment: While it was just my own mistake I thought it might help someone else on the training if they ever happen to do the same.  I think its the first time I've tried answering my own question so hopefully I've done it right.

Comment: I have 3 activities A1 => A2(parent A1) => A3(parent A2). If I use Android 2.3, I'll got a crash when A3 activity calls NatUtils which tries to extract parent of parent activity.

Answer (score 8):

I have the same problem. My problem was singly different. I specified ParentActivity with no full namespace in *AndroidStudio* IDE dialog. 
Naturally AndroidStudio generated a section in AndroidManifest.xml with no fully specified Class. I changed it manually by specifying full namespace in xml tag

```
<meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="____._____.MainActivity"/>
</activity>
```

Answer (score 2):

if you have such kind of exception follow this three steps:

1) Check if **package** in header of manifest file is correct and matches with package naming of your project:

```
<manifest package="com.my.project" ...>
```

2) Check if **applicationId** in **build.gradle** (Module:app) is correct and matches with package naming of your project:

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.my.project"
    ...
}
```

3) Check if **android:value** of parent activity written correctly.

```
<meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="._____.MainActivity"/>
</activity>
```

If first two steps are correct, so you don't need to write full namespace in **step 3**!