# bad parentActivityName in manifest

Tags: java, android, android-manifest

I am doing build your first app from Android. I get the following errors whenever I try to push the back button on the navigation at the top of my app:

```
E/Activity: getParentActivityIntent: bad parentActivityName 
'com.example.amir.myapplication.MainActivity' in manifest
E/NavUtils: getParentActivityIntent: bad parentActivityName 
'com.example.amir.myapplication.MainActivity' in manifest
```

This is my manifest.xml

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".DisplayMessageActivity"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">
        <!-- The meta-data tag is required if you support API level 15 and lower -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".MainActivity" />
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

My package is: package com.example.amir.myapplication. This is also my **applicaitonid** in **buildgradle**. Without the **intent-filter** I get the error that an intent-filter is required.

***DisplayMessageActivity***

```
public class DisplayMessageActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);

    // Get the Intent that started this activity and extract the string
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

    // Capture the layout's TextView and set the string as its text
    TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    textView.setText(message);
 }
}
```

***MainActivity***

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
public static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.myfirstapp.MESSAGE";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

/** Called when the user taps the send button */
public void sendMessage(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    String message = editText.getText().toString();
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
    startActivity(intent);
 }

}
```

*Please note that I am completely new to Java and Android developing. I followed one Java course and this is my first home project.*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does the up button cause an exception in the 'Building Your First App' Android training](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16325512/why-does-the-up-button-cause-an-exception-in-the-building-your-first-app-andro)

Comment: It is no duplicate that topic was facing other problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your manifest should include both the MainActivity and the DisplayMessageActivity. Right now you only have the DisplayMessageActivity, and you added the intent filter there. It should not have the intent filter, that should stay in MainActivity, since that is where the Intent is.

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".DisplayMessageActivity"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">
        <!-- The meta-data tag is required if you support API level 15 and lower -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".MainActivity" />
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: with this solution I get the following error: Error running 'DislayMessageActivity' The activity must be exported or contain an intent-filter

Comment: Did you change both activities in the manifest to match what I had (or you could even do everything in the application node)? I copied your code into Android Studio and that works for me.

Comment: I copy pasted exact your code then I go the error. See my printscreen please. https://i.imgur.com/4k1cJBR.png also note that I do not see the message that should show up. I will upload my entire code.

Comment: Select Run/Debug Configuration from my MainActivity to App. Then it runs and is working fine

Comment: Ah ok, good to hear! What was it set to other than "app" out of curiosity?

Comment: DislayMessageActivity